StoreContext.GetAppLicenseAsync returns no cached license when device is offline
This is a classic Win32 application distributed on MS Store.
At startup, it checks the status of the product license. See excerpt below (C++/WinRT):
#include <Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <Windows.System.h>
#include <Windows.Services.Store.h>

enum class LicenseStatus
{
    none,
    error,

    valid,
};

void Init()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();
}

LicenseStatus GetAppLicenseStatus()
{
    using namespace winrt::Windows::Services::Store;

    try {
        if (auto storeContext = StoreContext::GetDefault()) {
            if (auto storeProductRes = storeContext.GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync().get()) {
                if (auto storeProduct = storeProductRes.Product()) {
                    //auto storeId = storeProduct.StoreId();
                    if (auto appLicense = storeContext.GetAppLicenseAsync().get()) {
                        if (appLicense.IsActive()) {
                            return LicenseStatus::valid;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex) {
        return LicenseStatus::error;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex) {
        return LicenseStatus::error;
    }
}


When the device is offline GetAppLicenseAsync returns immediately. And the call to IsActive returns false. Previously, while online, it returned true.
Documentation [1]: "If this method is called while the device is offline, it returns the cached value of the current licenses on the device."
[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getapplicenseasync?view=winrt-22621

What is the question? The API seems to follow its documented contract. Which part of the behavior do you disagree with?

IsActive returns false. The license is valid. It should return true.

The validity of the license cannot be verified in offline mode. I would have expected an error, but false seems like a valid return value in this scenario. Do the other properties of StoreAppLicense return the expected values?
